# Deployment to heroku server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

I've deployed react app on heroku with express. And i get this error in console: Refused to load the image 'https://sporthelper.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Here is heroku deployed link https://sporthelper.herokuapp.com/

I've tried to change meta tag in myapp/public/index.html, but it didn't help.

This is my express server

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('sport_app/build'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'sport_app', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

And this one is from package.json of my server

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix sport_app && npm run build --prefix sport_app"
```

Comment: How were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using npm package `serve` instead of `server.js` script.
I added the following line to `package.json` scripts
`"start": "serve -s dist",`

Comment: now i have   "start": "node index.js", what should i do to dont get the crash when i execute heroku open? thanks

Comment: You should add heroku-postbuild to build your app, install serve package and change start to `"start": "serve -s dist",`

Comment: For a moment i set it correctly on heroku without postbuild, but don't know it doesn work now...

Comment: It doesn't work, im retrieving "The requested path could not be found 404" why?